# 20.04 server on raspberry pi 3 b+ when idle for more than 5 minutes

Tags: server, 20.04, raspberrypi, putty

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu server 20.04 LTS for the Raspberry Pi 3 B+. I have not installed anything on it but I have run `sudo apt-get update` and `upgrade`. I have it in a "dead head" so I just use Putty to remote in. I have not installed a desktop just using the command line to force my self to learn Linux commands.

While researching how to run Boinc rosetta@home (the reason I installed Ubuntu server on the Pi) through the command line I noticed that the Pi freezes and hard reboot is necessary to reconnect. It will consistently do this.

Google has failed me so I am reaching out to the community. I have little to no experience, this was meant to be a learning tool I guess it is but beyond my ability to troubleshoot. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note the time that you detect a freeze. After rebooting, look at /var/log/syslog (it's an ordinary text file) for the time it was frozen. Look for errors or warnings or clues that occurred right before the freeze. If you're not sure what you are reading, put the whole file into a [pastebin](http://paste.ubuntu.com) and add the link to your question. Also feel the pi itself -- does it happen to be running hot to the touch?

Comment: look at the end of the log of the previous boot: `sudo journalctl -b -1 -e`